# Populate Python dictionary from sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary

I am quite new to Python, but have previously done some work with databases and SQL code. I am wondering if/how it is possible to populate a Python dictionary with values of a specified `sqlite` table. I would like to create a dictionary where the ID of customers and factories forms a string, and the distance is used as the key for the dictionary (i.e. `dictionary(1,1):20`).

Here is what I have so far:

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys 

con = lite.connect('transport.sqlite')

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()    

dictionary = {}
cur.execute('SELECT idcustomer, idfactory, distance FROM distance')
result = cur.fetchall()

for idcustomer, idfactory, distance ...

con.close()

print dictionary
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to construct a dictionary using the distance as a key i.e. 20 => "CUSTID:FACTID" is:

```
dictionary = {}
cur.execute('select idcustomer,idfactory,distance from distance')
result = cur.fetchall()
for idcustomer, idfactory, distance in result:
   dictionary[distance] = "{}:{}".format(idcustomer, idfactory)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but I get a syntax error in the line for idcustomer, idfactory, distance:". Wouldn't i normally need an "in", to specify until what point the loop is supposed to continue to run?

Comment: @user3222343 I think it was the for statement. Can you try the edited code above?

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion, and it runs smoothly now! Thanks a lot